# Is it possible to share a wifi connection through ethernet while keeping the same DHCP server?

Tags: networking, netplan, network-bridge

I need to add a Jetson Nano to a robot and I'd like to use a single wifi interface to communicate outside of the robot.

My network setup should look like this:

```
Server <--eth--> Router <--wlan--> Jetson <--eth--> RaspberryPi4
```

In order to be able to use the [ROS](https://www.ros.org/) framework, I need to setup the network to enable two way communications for all devices. Basically, I need to be able to ping the RaspberryPi4 from the Server.

I have worked in the past with a wifi extender that was able to share wifi to ethernet while using the DHCP server of the Router. I'm wondering how to replicate that behavior using a netplan config.

How can I bridge the Jetson wlan0 and eth0 interfaces while providing an IP address to the RaspberryPi4 that's from the Router DHCP server?

Answer (score 1):

I found these tutorials. They allowed me to setup the network in a way that works.

- https://risc.readthedocs.io/2-ros-network-wifi-ethernet.html
- https://github.com/ethz-asl/mav_dji_ros_interface/wiki/NVIDIA-Jetson-TX2-integration#multi-device-network-setup